# how do you update multiple tables with 1 query

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

i have a 2 tables that have data in them that id like to update with 1 button click.

```
using (SQLiteCommand cmd = connAccount.CreateCommand())
{
      cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE account SET balance = accrued + balance, accrued = 0 WHERE active = 1";
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

thats the code im using to update the 1 table but there is a2nd table, customer, where id let to set the allowance to 15000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this query:

```
@"BEGIN TRANSACTION; UPDATE account SET balance = accrued + balance, accrued = 0 WHERE active = 1; 
UPDATE Customer ..... ;  COMMIT;";
```

Try to use parameters instead of string values.

Comment: thatnks that works great, i added paremeters at the same time

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a method and just pass the query on the parameters of the method like this

```
public void UpdateData(string query)
{
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = connAccount.CreateCommand())
    {
           cmd.CommandText = query;
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

And then you can call this method twice on on your button_click event

```
private void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateData("Update (YourFirstTable to update)");
    UpdateData("Update (YourSecondTable to update)");

}
```